# TYPO3 - Detect Browser Size with Fluid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, typo3, typoscript, fluid

I search for a Browser Size Solution in a TYPO3 FLUID-Template.
I need a Condition `if/else` for different Browser-Size (Mobile and Desktop), then I can load different Templates for Mobile and Desktop.
At the time I use `Bootstrap4` for the Switch, but on the website I have duplicate Code.
A better Solution is a "Browser-Size" Switch in the `TYPO3` Fluid Template.

Answer (score 4):

PHP inluding Fluid have no access ways to detect the browsers with. You can at least access the User Agent which maybe can give you some hints which kind of device a user is using. To detect the actual browser size which can be changed at any time you can only use CSS or Javascript.

To make the browser size accessible to TYPO3 / FLUID templates you maybe store the size of the browser inside a cookie with Javascript. In PHP you can read that cookie using `$_COOKIE` which could be passed to your Fluid Templates.

Answer (score 2):

But note that if you use the cookie approach outlined by Paul Beck that you must take care of proper caching if your plugin is cached. So you'd have to add cache tags depending on the cookie value.